# Perl Unicode test on OS X fails on Debian

Tags: perl, unicode

I have the following test:

```
use Test::More;
use Lingua::EN::NameCase 'nc';
use utf8;
my $output = Test::Builder->new->todo_output;
binmode $output, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
$output = Test::Builder->new->failure_output;
binmode $output, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $name = 'Lintão';
is nc($name), $name, 'nc() should not change a properly namecased name';
diag nc($name);

done_testing;
```

On Mac OS X with Perl 5.10.1, I get the following output:

```
nc.t ..
ok 1 - nc() should not change a properly namecased name
1..1
# Lintão
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.07 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Unfortunately, the same test on Debian Squeezebox, with 5.10.1 Perl produces this output:

```
nc.t ..
not ok 1 - nc() should not change a properly namecased name

#   Failed test 'nc() should not change a properly namecased name'
#   at nc.t line 10.
#          got: 'LintãO'
#     expected: 'Lintão'
# LintãO
1..1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
nc.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.03 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.04 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

The offending line in the `nc()` subroutine appears to be this:

```
s{ \b (\w)   }{\u$1}gox ;           # Uppercase first letter of every word.
```

So somehow, the same version of Perl on Debian is getting the word boundary wrong. Can anyone help me debug further?

Comment: I'm not running Squeeze, but an Ubuntu. Can reproduce with perl 5.18.1 with L::EN::NC v1.15.

Comment: Interesting bit I can't yet make sense of: Everything works if we decompose the string to NFD or NFKD. The failure only occurs with NFC and NFKC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The locale on your Linux box doesn't consider `ã` a word character (`Lingua::EN::NameCase` has `use locale;` so it uses the current `LC_CTYPE` setting for character classification). With perlbrewed perls ranging from 5.8.1 to 5.18.1 I get this output consitently on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with `en_GB.UTF-8` locale:

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -le 'print 0+("ã" =~ /\w/); use locale; print 0+("ã" =~ /\w/)'
1
0
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. `ã` is encoded as `\xE3`, which is a single byte. Thus, the locale rules apply. By introducing a multi-byte character into the string, we can force unicode semantics, as noted in perldoc perlre. These rules are frustratingly complex.

Comment: No, single/multi-byte doesn't enter into it, only `use locale;` and the locale's idea of what's a word character. I've edited the response to demonstrate this.

Comment: I'm still unsure of the fix, then. I tried setting LC_CTYPE='UTF-8' in a BEGIN block, but I still get the same failure. Short of monkey-patching Lingua::EN::NameCase, how do I resolve this?

Comment: `LC_CTYPE` takes `<language>_<country>.<encoding>`, not just the encoding (since different languages have different ideas of character classifications) Setting the environment variable in a BEGIN {} block is too late, since it's set by libc on startup. You'd need `setlocale()`, but that probably won't help either, since the Linux `en_GB.UTF-8` locale doesn't consider 'ã' a word character. I'd patch `Lingua::EN::NameCase` to have an option to use Unicode instead of locale definitions.